# Different result in PyCharm using split()

Tags: python, split, pycharm

When I run the same code in different consoles I get a different output.

The code:

```
`import numpy as np
input_1 = '2 2'
input_2 = '1 2\n3 4'
N, M = map(int, input_1.split())
my_arr = [list(map(int, input_2.split())) for _ in range(N)]
print(np.prod(np.sum(my_arr, axis=0)))`
```

The output that I expect is 24 (1+3 = 4, 2+4 =6 -> 4*6 = 24)

When I run this code in PyCharm using Python 3.11 the output that I get is 384

When I run this code in another console hosted by hackerrank or Chat GPT I get 24 (expected answer).

Does anyone know why this difference is occurring?

I have checked out step-by-step what is happening in PyCharm and the output from:

```
`import numpy as np
input_1 = '2 2'
input_2 = '1 2\n3 4'
N, M = map(int, input_1.split())
my_arr = [list(map(int, input_2.split())) for _ in range(N)]
print(my_arr)`
```

is:

```
`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`
```

Which is where the 'error' is occurring - I would have thought that the 5th line would output:

```
`[[1,2],[3,4]]`
```

which it does in the other consoles

Comment: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]` is what you should get from the 5th line just by reading your code. I see no way that you can get `[[1,2],[3,4]]` from it.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/np-sum-and-prod/problem?isFullScreen=true

If you enter the code:
`import numpy as np
N, M = map(int, input().split())
my_arr = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(N)]
print(np.prod(np.sum(my_arr, axis=0)))`
Into that console and the input is:
2 2
1 2
3 4
The output is 24??

I thought that input matched what I split out the input to be?

Comment: Yep as @blhsing stated, I've tested the code (on vscode), it makes sense you'd get 384. Maybe check your code? And Milbot, I don't think your code works, sorry. I think your error is on line 3, have a look. I might be wrong, but I noticed you never used the variable `M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace line 4 with

```py
my_arr = [list(int(i) for i in input_2.split()[0:N]),] + [list(int(i) for i in input_2.split()[N:M+N]),]
```

Hopefully it works. There might be a simpler way, but this should work.